# At what point during Java NIO Socket on the server or client end is the socket connection ready to send data?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm working with Java NIO and this is my first time setting up a working TCP connection (I've only done UDP up until this point and a simple TCP test program a long time ago).

Right now, I'm unsure the exact moment where I can reliably start sending data to the clients such that they know there is an active connection on the other end (*assuming something hasn't gone wrong*).

---

Assume everything is non-blocking.

CLIENT:

1) Open a new socket channel with no bindings so it can be set to async

```
s = SocketChannel.open()
```

2) Set it to be non-blocking

```
s.configureBlocking(false)
```

- Do we need to bind here? Or is that just for if we want to refer to a local port?

3) Attempt to connect to a server that is listening

```
s.connect(someAddr)
```

- If this returns true, the javadocs say the connection is established. Does that mean I don't need to call finishConnect()? From what I read, this is for local connections, but it does not specify if remote connections could possibly return true immediately or not.
- Is this where the client sends a SYN to the server?

---

SERVER:

4) Server gets an incoming connection through some `serverSocketChannel.accept()`, which we assume is non blocking and will pretend in this case it returns a valid socket object (and not null).

- Does this mean that as soon as the server gets the connection, it accepted the connection (assuming all went well) and sends back a SYN-ACK?

---

CLIENT:

5) Does the client call `finishConnect()` now?

- When does the client know when to keep calling finishConnect()? Do I just loop for X seconds immediately after calling `s.connect(...)` from step (3)?
- Is this when it sends the ACK? Am I supposed to loop for X seconds until it returns true... and kill the 'half formed connection' if it doesn't respond within X seconds due to something going wrong?
- Does `s.isConnected()` return true for the connect() in step (3) succeeding, or finishConnect() succeeding?

---

I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly, and I'm also not sure at what point is it safe for the server to send, or the client to send... is it at (4) for the server, and (5) for the client?

Do I need to have the client send a heartbeat packet after the connection is done to the server so my application knows it's okay to start sending data? I don't know how the server would know it's fully connected since I can't see any way the **server** would know when the final acknowledgement is done... except for the client knowing the connection is established and it sends some kind of 'first packet' data.

The only way the server would know is if I can somehow figure out when it gets the ACK packet, but I can't see a way of Java letting me know currently.

*NOTE:* I may be missing knowledge, I may have said some incorrect stuff, if you can point out where they are wrong I'd be more than glad to update my post so it's factually correct.

Links that guided my knowledge/creation of this post:

[TCP protocol](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml)

[SocketChannel Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)

Comment: In order to use a client socket, you should be using the `new Socket()` call.  A `SocketChannel` is something else.  [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

Comment: @markspace I thought when you open a new `SocketChannel`, you open a Socket as well with NIO, which you can access with `s.socket()` with this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#socket%28%29 ... are you saying that the above is incorrect?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you don't understand TCP/IP, you should probably use plain sockets and stay away from NIO.  NIO is touchy and difficult, it's not for newbies.

Comment: @markspace That was a garbage red-herring answer. I have no problem using NIO and I've used it before, it's not as hard as you're pretending it is. I could go on about how you're not reading the question, but instead I'll ask you that if you know anything about this -- how about you actually try to answer the question instead of having a trash attitude and polluting my question with stuff that is dragging it off topic. So, enlighten us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do we need to bind here? Or is that just for if we want to refer to a local port?

You don't need to bind the client `SocketChannel`.

```
s.connect(someAddr)
```

> If this returns true, the javadocs say the connection is established. Does that mean I don't need to call `finishConnect()`?

Correct.

> From what I read, this is for local connections

From what you read where? No truth in that.

> but it does not specify if remote connections could possibly return true immediately or not.

It can return true any time. You have to check. And it has nothing to do with local or remote.

> Is this where the client sends a SYN to the server?

Yes.

> Server gets an incoming connection through some `serverSocketChannel.accept()`, which we assume is non blocking and will pretend in this case it returns a valid socket object (and not null). Does this mean that as soon as the server gets the connection, it accepted the connection (assuming all went well) and sends back a SYN-ACK?

No. The SYN-ACK has already been sent by the TCP/IP stack. It doesn't depend on when the application code calls `accept()`.

> Does the client call `finishConnect()` now?

Again this doesn't depend on when the server application called `accept()`. The TCP handshake is completed by the server kernel. The client should call `finishConnnect()` if `connect()` didn't return true and a subsequent `select()` indicates that the channel is now connectable.

Note that `finishConnect()` can return true, in which case you just proceed, or false, in which case you just keep waiting for `OP_CONNECT`: or it can throw an exception, in which case it failed and you must close the channel.

> When does the client know when to keep calling `finishConnect()`? Do I just loop for X seconds immediately after calling `s.connect(...)` from step (3)?

See above. But if you're prepared to just loop, why do the connect in non-blocking mode at all? Do it in blocking mode and go into non-blocking mode when it succeeds. Much simpler.

> Is this when it sends the ACK?

No. That is all done by the kernel asynchronosusly

> Am I supposed to loop for X seconds until it returns true... and kill the 'half formed connection' if it doesn't respond within X seconds due to something going wrong?

No, see above.

> Does `s.isConnected()` return true for the `connect()` in step (3) succeeding, or `finishConnect()` succeeding?

Both: they're mutually exclusive.

> I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly, and I'm also not sure at what point is it safe for the server to send, or the client to send... is it at (4) for the server, and (5) for the client?

The server can send as soon as it has an accepted socket. The client can send as soon as either `connect()` or `finishConnect(`) returns true.

> Do I need to have the client send a heartbeat packet after the connection is done to the server so my application knows it's okay to start sending data?

No.

> I don't know how the server would know it's fully connected since I can't see any way the server would know when the final acknowledgement is done... except for the client knowing the connection is established and it sends some kind of 'first packet' data.

See above. The idea of sending a packet to see if you can send a packet doesn't make sense.

> The only way the server would know is if I can somehow figure out when it gets the ACK packet

The server already has the ACK packet when `accept()` returns.

> NOTE: I may be missing knowledge ...

What you're overlooking is the existence of the listen backlog queue at the server.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat:  I've done my socket programming using sockets, and not socketchannels.  This answer is based on reading the SocketChannel javadoc, knowing that socketchannels use sockets behind the scenes and being familiar with sockets.

According to the javadoc, if connect() returns true, the connection is established, and you don't need to call finishConnect().  Think of finishConnect() as a way of checking on the status of connection establishment, rather than as a function that does anything required to establish a connection.

On the server, if accept() returns a SocketChannel, then the connection attempt has been received from the client.  The SYN ACK from the server has most likely been sent, although the Java documentation purposely does not specify this, in order to permit future optimizations.  Most likely the connection is considered by Java to be "established", though you could call finishConnect() to make sure; it's possible Java waits until the server gets the client's ACK before it considers the connection fully established.  Note that the Javadoc specifies that the returned SocketChannel will initially be in blocking mode, even if the ServerSocketChannel was in nonblocking mode.

On the client side, you can start sending data as soon as either connect() or finishConnect() returns true.  On the server side, you can certainly start sending data when finishConnect() returns true; it may be that the call to finishConnect() is superfluous and accept() returns a SocketChannel with an established connection - that's how I would have written it - but I haven't used SocketChannels enough to be sure.  You do not need to send a heartbeat packet during connection establishment and doing so would probably be a waste of effort, as the TCP protocol itself handles all the connection related stuff, including the three way handshake (SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK) to establish the connection.

Comment: You seem to think it's Java that sends SYN and ACK. It isn't: it's the underlying TCP/IP stack The BSD sockets documentation doesn't specify when they are sent either, so it isn't possible for the Javadoc to do so. You don't call finishConnect() at the server.

Comment: @EJP I don't see how you get that from my answer.  I said the "server" (not Java) sends the SYN ACK.  The "server" might have BSD, Windows, or another operating system.  That's why I used words like "considered by Java to be" - to differentiate between what Java knows about the state of the world and what's actually going on in the server's TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Also, if it's true that the final ACK of the three way handshake has been received at the server when accept() returns a SocketChannel, as your answer states and I assume to be true, then clearly the JVM can determine if the ACK has been received, and thus that could be documented in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Selector to wait on CONNECT and ACCEPT events.

NIO is not that hard. But Java's NIO API is a little harder than necessary. Have fun torturing yourself:)

---

The exact mapping between  Java API calls and TCP handshake steps is not very clear. However, I would think of it in the following model (it doesn't matter much if it is not exactly what's happening in reality)

```
 connect() 
                     -- SYN -->
                    <-- ACK --
                    <-- SYN --  
 CONNECT event
 finishConnect()        
                     -- ACK -->
                                   ACCEPT event
                                   accept()
```

Sequences:

- client app calls `connect(serverAddress)` - client sends SYN to server

if `connect()` returns true, the socket channel can be used immeidately. however, I've never observed this case in practice, not even on local loopback connections.

- server receives client SYN; responds with ACK/SYN
- client receives server ACK/SYN.
- a CONNECT event is raised to client app.
- cilent app then calls `finishConnect()` - client sends ACK to server

Here, `finishConnect()` will not return false, because of the previous CONNECT event. It could throw exception though.

Now, client considers TCP handshake complete. The client socket channel can be used immediately.

- server receives client ACK. server considers TCP handshake complete. the connection is put in the backlog.
- an ACCEPT event is raised to server app.
- server app then calls `accept()`. The returned socket channel can be used immediately.

Comment: The final ACK does not depend on the client calling finishConnect(). This method can indeed return false: see the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP - As my disclaimer said, it's a model you can use to reason about the API calls, it may not correspond to exact TCP actions. And once the `CONNECT` event is received, a subsequence `finishConnect()` should return true or throw Exception - at least I've never observed `false`.

Comment: I have to agree with @EJP that this answer is misleading; in particular, it seems to imply that finishConnect() must be called to return the client ACK, which is not true.  Also note that finishConnect() can only return false if the channel is in nonblocking mode, which may (or may not) explain why you've never seen it.

Comment: @WarrenDew - It's equally wrong to say definitively that `ACK` does not require `finishConnect()` call. As I said, the API spec is vague, and I'm providing a model that works for APIs users, even if it's not exactly what's happening for a particular JDK.

Comment: @WarrenDew - You are implying that I'm answering an NIO question, while I never dealt  with nonblocking mode. I'm happy to report that I am not that stupid, thanks.

Comment: I agree the Javadoc is vague, but it's quite clear from the fact that connect() can return true - and indeed cannot return false if the channel is in blocking mode - that finishConnect() is not necessary to send the ACK.

Comment: Regarding NIO, the fact that SocketChannel defaults to blocking mode suggests that its writers expect most of its users to use blocking mode.  If you believe that it's only worth using NIO if you need the asynchronous capabilities of nonblocking mode, and you might well be right on that, that would probably be very useful information to include in an answer.

Comment: @WarrenDew - In the context of my answer, the channel is in nonblocking mode; connect() returned false; CONNECT event arrives; before `finishConnect()` is called.

Comment: If it's only an incorrect model what exactly is the point of it? Why not fix it so it's correct?